# timyMCE HTML tag not working in HTML email

Tags: email, tinymce, html-email

When I write in tinymce editor as follows:

```
Lorem
Lorem Ipsium
Lorem
```

It shows in my email:

```
 <p>Lorem</p>
 <p>Lorem Ipsium</p>
 <p>Lorem</p>
```

When I write an email in multilines, it shows all lines as one. Please help me or suggest me what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the entire code of your email?  If `<p>` tags are in email and do not have any style associated with them, it will create multilines per each `<p>` tag.